# how to redirect to a html page in root folder from a php script in sub folder?

Tags: php, html

Am working with XAMPP

Root folder has a file called homepage.php

I want to redirect to homepage.php from a php script in folder admin/teacher/run.php

how to specify the path to homepage.php in root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what are you trying to achieve, if you need to redirect the page programmatically then the best option IMO is this

```
<?php
header('location: /hompage.php');
exit();
```

if you do not need to process anything in php you could use a redirection in the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: /homepage.php");
exit;
```

The `exit;` is required to prevent PHP sending any more information to the browser after the redirect request.